# Thermodynamics, how can i do this with steam?

Tags: thermodynamics, steam

I have a problem with thermodynamics.
I have this question:

$q_{12} = ?$ Steam heating in constant volume. $p_1 = 1.76$ bar. Steam quality: $x_1 = 0.7$;  $T_2 = 200$ Celsius.
Where ’1’ is the current state of the steam, and ’2’ is the goal state.
What I need for this task is:

- $h_1$, $s_1$, $p_1 = 1.76$ bar, $v_1$, $u_1$
- $h”$ $s”$ $p”$ $v”$ $u”$ $t”$ (the line between the liquid-vapor and vapor region)
- $h_2$, $s_2$, $p_2$, $v_2$, $t_2 = 200$ Celsius

My question is that how could I calculate this from a steam table? I know that this is isochoric changing, so $v =$ constant, but I couldn’t find any solution on the internet.

Thanks guys! I really appreciate it. It makes me mad for days :)